# Calling a yii Class in a non object oriented php script

Tags: php, yii

i am working on a voting section of my website built over Yii framework,i am using ajax to call a php script that should load an Answer model and increment the positive/negative vote,however this script cant access model Class of Answers,if i use `require_once('Answer.php')` it gives me `ActiveRecord.php Class not found`,..my script file is not a Class so i cant extend ActiveRecord Class ,i am wondering if there is a way i can load Answer model in my script without messing around with Yii code,i am a newbie on yii,Thanks
here is my js

```
function downVoteAnswer(id){
    var data= $.get("/codepacu/protected/models/votehandler.php",function(data){
    $('#ans-downvote-'+id).text(data);
    });

    }
```

Here is my php script file

```
require_once('Answer.php');
$model=Answer::loadModel(4);
$model->up_vote=$model->up_vote++;
$model->save();
echo $model->up_vote;
```

Comment: why not write an action in a controller and access that from ajax?? The model is extended from ActiveRecord class which is automatically loaded by Yii. Thats why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is nothing specific to Yii, it is so with any PHP code:

You can only use a class when it's definition is available. In your case, the definition is only loaded partly. You already load the file `Answer.php` for the `Answer` model class, but that class is defined in more than one file.

So this requires you more files to load. Identify all needed classes and require the related files.

This can be a lot, so it is normally better to create some ajax controller endpoint within Yii itself.

- [Update content in AJAX with renderPartial (yiiframework wiki)](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/)
- [Simple Yii ajaxLink (by Bryan Marble; 12 May 2010)](http://lostmahbles.com/simple-yii-ajaxlink/)
- [Make ajax request in yii framework (by Handita Okviyanto; 2 Mar 2012)](http://mrhandscode.blogspot.de/2012/03/make-ajax-request-in-yii-framework.html)

Comment: @ElieGateteMagambo if the answer helped you should click on the green tick next to it to accept it :)